# Array size in NxN matrix - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix

May I know how I can get the array size of NxN matrix

like number of rows and no: of columns where my input is 4x4

```
arr[4][4]
```

Is it something like `arr[N].count` for rows and `arr[][N].count` for columns?

Please advice

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html Scroll down to just over half way

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code. Show how you declared your "matrix".

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in `Array` type, you cannot create a two-dimensional `Array` (which you refer to as matrix) that's guaranteed to be *"NxN"*, because you cannot guarantee that all inner arrays will have the same number of elements and you also cannot guarantee that the number of elements in the inner arrays will be the same as the number of arrays in the two-dimensional array.

However, you can access the number of inner arrays (or *"rows"*) using `arr.count` and you can access the number of elements in the inner arrays using `arr[i].count` (which will be the number of *"columns"* assuming that all inner arrays have the same number of elements).

If you'll be using two-dimensional `Array`s a lot and you want to guarantee that all of the inner arrays have the same number of elements, I'd suggest creating a custom `Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` or `endIndex` to get the dimensions but you need to check each row separately.

```
var matrix: [[Int]] = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9]]

print(matrix.count)

for i in 0..<matrix.endIndex {
    print(matrix[i].endIndex)
}
```